# Boxed trait object is still an unknown size

Tags: rust

#### The Error:

So I'm getting the following error:

`error[E0277]: the size for values of type 'dyn Getter' cannot be known at compilation time`

```rust
struct PlusFive;

impl Operator for PlusFive {
    fn apply<'a>(&self, a: &'a dyn Getter) -> Box<dyn Getter + 'a> {
        Box::new(MapGetter {
            source: a, // A pointer to some Getter
            f: |n:i32| n + 5 // A way to later compute +5 on source
        });
    }
}
```

- the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `dyn Getter`
- the trait `Getter` is implemented for `MapGetter<T, F>`

---

#### The Question:

I'm not sure what this errors means or how to resolve it. The size `dyn Getter` can't be known, but the size of MapGetter certainly can! and Since MapGetter is a concrete type that implements the Getter trait, I don't see why I can't Box this up and return it.

I'm missing something here. I **can** Box up the `MapGetter`, what I can't do is lift it into a trait object?

Here's the full example I'm working with if it helps to see it all in context:

---

#### Note:

On the whole, I've been trying to do this with dynamic dispatch. In part because I want to see what can be done and in part because I foresee myself wanting a list of `dyn Operator`s where the concrete types underneath may vary.

I don't want to attach operators to the `Getter` trait directly because eventually I want the operators to represent re-usable pieces of logic, so they can be applied to a `Getter` after the fact (or more than once)

#### Full Context:

```rust
trait Getter {
    fn compute(&self) -> i32;

    fn pipe(&self, operator: &dyn Operator) -> Box<dyn Getter>
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        operator.apply(&self)
    }
}

impl<T: Getter> Getter for &T {
    fn compute(&self) -> i32 {
        (*self).compute()
    }
}

impl<T: Getter> Getter for Box<T> {
    fn compute(&self) -> i32 {
        (*self).compute()
    }
}

struct PureGetter<T>(T);

impl Getter for PureGetter<i32> {
    fn compute(&self) -> i32 {
        self.0
    }
}

struct MapGetter<T, F> {
    source: T,
    f: F,
}

impl<T, F> Getter for MapGetter<T, F>
where
    T: Getter,
    F: FnMut(i32) -> i32 + Clone,
{
    fn compute(&self) -> i32 {
        (self.f.clone())(self.source.compute())
    }
}

trait Operator {
    fn apply<'a>(&self, a: &'a dyn Getter) -> Box<dyn Getter + 'a>;
}

struct PlusFive;

impl Operator for PlusFive {
    fn apply<'a>(&self, a: &'a dyn Getter) -> Box<dyn Getter + 'a> {
        Box::new(MapGetter {
            source: a,
            f: |n:i32| n + 5
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let result = PureGetter(0).pipe(&PlusFive).compute();
    println!("{:#?}", result);
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `dyn Getter` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/main.rs:71:9
   |
71 | /         Box::new(MapGetter {
72 | |             source: a,
73 | |             f: |n:i32| n + 5
74 | |         })
   | |__________^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `dyn Getter`
   = help: the trait `Getter` is implemented for `MapGetter<T, F>`
note: required for `&dyn Getter` to implement `Getter`
  --> src/main.rs:24:17
   |
24 | impl<T: Getter> Getter for &T {
   |                 ^^^^^^     ^^
   = note: 1 redundant requirement hidden
   = note: required for `MapGetter<&dyn Getter, [closure@src/main.rs:73:16: 73:23]>` to implement `Getter`
   = note: required for the cast from `MapGetter<&dyn Getter, [closure@src/main.rs:73:16: 73:23]>` to the object type `dyn Getter`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `messin` due to previous error
```

Comment: Why are you  not adding the trait bounds on the structs, instead of the implementations. You'll get much clearer errors

Comment: Could you add the full error, as provided by `cargo check`? I've tried to look through your code in the playground, but fixing the immediate issue lead to the couple of new ones. so I'm not sure whether it's the same thing you see.

Comment: @Cerberus Sure, I've updated the question with the full error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minimized example for this specific error:

```
trait Getter {}

impl<T: Getter> Getter for &T {}

impl Getter for () {}

fn main() {
    let getter: &dyn Getter = &();
    let getter: Box<dyn Getter> = Box::new(getter);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4cde82226d3aef09c020415a151c7561)

The reason is the following:

- To create a `Box<dyn Getter>` from `Box<&dyn Getter>`, `&dyn Getter` must implement `Getter` itself.
- `&T` has a blanket implementation for `Getter`.
- But the generic parameter of this implementation has an implicit `Sized` bound, therefore it can't be applied to `&dyn Getter`.

To fix the immediate problem, you can simply [relax the bound](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1f6e310c309ae477bbdb5bec544bb04c):

```
impl<T: Getter + ?Sized> Getter for &T {}
```

In your original code, the reasoning is similar, just with one more intermediate step - you have to pass `impl Getter` to `MapGetter`, so that `MapGetter` is `Getter` itself; but the passed-in value is `&dyn Getter`, which isn't `Getter` for the reasons above.

---

As an aside, I'd say that it is quite unidiomatic to have both references and `Box`es at the same time. You'd probably have an easier way if you restricted yourself to only one of them - either loaning the temporary references all the way down, or `Box`ing everything to own everything.

Comment: I looks like you're passing a reference to a getter into `Box::new()` (which, in this case **is** itself a getter). Does the box now own a reference or the actual data?

Comment: @MrkSef They typed it as `Box<dyn Getter>`, so Rust will auto-deref and box the actual data. If that type annotation wasn't there, it would box the reference (`getter` is a reference).

Comment: @FZs, I think that's the piece of the puzzle I'm missing

Comment: @MrkSef But do you understand it now?

Comment: @FZs I'll toy about with it a bit more and probably make the same mistake again, but I understand it well enough to reason through it when it's pointed out to me. The beginning of enlightenment. My next issue is that `.pipe` doesn't exist on trait objects (due to the self: Sized) bound. But that's a separate question if I can't figure it out.

Comment: "They typed it as Box<dyn Getter>, so Rust will auto-deref and box the actual data" - it won't, that's the point. It have to coerce `&dyn Getter` to `dyn Getter`, which is possible only if `&dyn Getter: Getter`.